# Convert a byte to a negative integer?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a byte `\ca` that I want to convert to `-54` not `202`

Is there a function that does this or do I have to do this math in my code?

Here is my code:

```
    def load_sv_str(self, byte_str):
        byte_data = self.unpack_byte_data(byte_str)
        self.my_char = byte_data[0]
```

`self.my_char` keeps getting 202 when it should get -54

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `int.from_bytes()`. Make sure you use `signed=True` as it's a signed char:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b"\xca", "little", signed=True)
-54
```

Comment: Hmm... I get an error:

`TypeError: cannot convert 'int' object to bytes`

Comment: Strange that a byte indexed from a byte array is an `int`.

Comment: Fixed. To get a single byte you must use a slice `byte_data[0:1]`

Comment: @RaySalemi Glad I could help :-) you may accept the answer if it solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `struct.unpack()` like so:

```
>>> struct.unpack("b", b"\xca")[0]
-54
```

`"b"` is the format for a signed byte.